# Is there a way to dynamically implement a trait/interface

Tags: java, scala

I am partially rewriting a java project in scala. For the persistence layer in the project I have a set of entities defined as interfaces with concrete implementations. I am rewriting the persistence layer with squeryl. I am trying to establish the most efficient way to bridge these types when calling the legacy code which will refer to these interfaces. So I have say in my legacy java code the following interface:

```
public interface Author
{
  public void setName(String name);
  public String getName();
  // etc
}

void someLegacyFunc(Author author) // ...
```

And then in my new scala code I would have the following squeryl object

```
class Author (
  val name: String;
  // etc ...
)
```

I know I can bridge these two doing the following:

```
class AuthorBridge(author: Author) implemenets legacy.Author {

  public void setName(String: name) = author.name = name
  public String getName() = author.name
  // etc.
}
```

However it is a very large library and I would like to avoid having to define a whole new set of bridge objects if possible. I am wondering if scala reflection might provide some more dynamic way of doing this along the following lines:

```
object Bridge {

  def get[Legacy, Entity](entity: Entity): Legacy {

  // builds an anonymous implementation of Legacy 
  // binding all the getter/setter methods to the entity's attributes

  }

}

val legacyAuthor = getAuthor(author)
```

Thanks
Des

Comment: Behind the scenes, Scala traits are realized as a *helper* class plus and interface.  When a class mixes in a trait, the Scala compiler produces a Java class that implements the interface so that it delegates to the *helper* class.  This all happens at compile time and therefore you cannot mixin traits at runtime.